# Прогресс загрузки файла на ftp

Tags: python, ftp

Загружаю файл на ftp простой командой:

```
ftp.storbinary("STOR " + file, open(file, "rb"), 1024)
```

файл загружается корректно, однако, безлико. Весь процесс заливки файла проходит в глухом ожидании.

Возможно ли получать какую-нибудь информацию о ходе загрузки файла. Процент загрузки, оставшееся время, размер загруженный, или оставшийся загрузить, в общем хоть что-то что возможно преобразовать в прогрессбар на сайте?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[FTP.storbinary(command, file[, blocksize, callback, rest])](http://docs.python.org/library/ftplib.html#ftplib.FTP.storbinary)

> Store a file in binary transfer mode. command should be an appropriate STOR command: "STOR filename". file is an open file object which is read until EOF using its read() method in blocks of size blocksize to provide the data to be stored. The blocksize argument defaults to 8192. **callback is an optional single parameter callable that is called on each block of data after it is sent**. rest means the same thing as in the transfercmd() method.

Соответственно получить информацию о процессе загрузки можно примерно следующим образом:

```
def progress():
    def callback(block):
        callback.uploaded += len(block)
        print('Uploaded %d bytes' % callback.uploaded)
    callback.uploaded = 0
    return callback

ftp.storbinary("STOR " + file, open(file, "rb"), 1024, progress())
```

Comment: Идеальное решение. Всё четко. Спасибо.